# Deja Dup (default backup utility) fails to install necessary software

Tags: 16.04, unity, backup, deja-dup, dbus

Before you can start using `deja-dup`, you have to click `Install...` in the Backups window, for `deja-dup` to "first install some necessary software".

When I click the `Install...` button, I get this error message:

> **Could not install**
>
> GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PackageKit was not provided by any .service files

I desperately tried `sudo apt-get -f install` because I had no other idea, but it did not solve this.

### Just some information about my machine:

I'm running ubuntu 16.04:

`uname -srvio`

> Linux 4.10.0-42-generic #46~16.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Dec 4 15:57:59 UTC
>   2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

`lsb_release -a`

> `No LSB modules are available. 
>   Distributor ID: Ubuntu
>   Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
>   Release:    16.04 
>   Codename:   xenial`

`deja-dup --version`

> `deja-dup 34.2`

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to manually install duplicity:

```
$ sudo apt-get install duplicity
$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-gi
```

Then close and re-open the backup tool